# Disparate Logical returns working with datetimes created with as.POSIXct()

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, dplyr, logical-operators

Rephrasing original question to add more clarity and reproducible code:

The code below is what I am using to label various time segments of my hydrograph. When I run it no errors are returned.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(lubridate)
library(zoo)
library(trend)

## Original Data

test_df = data.frame(test_date=c("8/1/2023","8/1/2023","8/1/2023", "7/31/2023","7/31/2023","8/1/2023"),
                      T1=c("16:18:00","17:41:00","18:58:00","23:09:00","23:47:00","0:29:00"),
                      T2=c("17:34:00","18:52:00","19:56:00","23:44:00","0:28:00","1:21:00"),
                      mid_time=c("16:56:00","18:16:30","19:27:00","23:26:30","0:07:30","0:55:00"))

# data processing
test_df = test_df %>%
  mutate(DateTime1=as.POSIXct(with(test_df, as.Date(test_date,"%m/%d/%y%y")+hms(T1)))) %>%
  mutate(DateTime2=as.POSIXct(with(test_df, as.Date(test_date,"%m/%d/%y%y")+hms(T2)))) %>%
  mutate(midtime_date=as.POSIXct(with(test_df, as.Date(test_date,"%m/%d/%y%y")+hms(mid_time)))) 

# original attempt
test_df = test_df %>%

  mutate(Tide=ifelse(midtime_date>="2023-07-31 18:14:00 UTC" & midtime_date<"2023-07-31 23:22:00 UTC","EBB",
                     ifelse(midtime_date>="2023-07-31 23:22:00 UTC" & midtime_date<="2023-07-31 23:59:00 UTC","Flood",
                     ifelse(midtime_date>="2023-08-01 00:00:00 UTC" & midtime_date<"2023-08-01 04:08:00 UTC","Flood",
                     ifelse(midtime_date>="2023-08-01 04:08:00 UTC" & midtime_date<"2023-08-01 11:30:00 UTC","Ebb",
                     ifelse(midtime_date>="2023-08-01 11:30:00 UTC" & midtime_date<"2023-08-01 18:52:00 UTC","Flood",
                     ifelse(midtime_date>="2023-08-01 18:52:00 UTC" & midtime_date<"2023-08-02 00:00:00 UTC","Ebb",
                                                        "NA" )))))))
#logical: these two statements should be equal but aren't
test_df$midtime_date[6]>"2023-08-01 00:00:00 UTC"
"2023-08-01 00:55:00 UTC">"2023-08-01 00:00:00 UTC"

# What I want
test_df = test_df %>%

  mutate(Tide=ifelse(test_date=="2023-07-31",
                     ifelse(hms(T1)>= hms("18:14:00") & hms(T1)<hms("23:22:00"), "Ebb", "Flood" ),
                     
                     ifelse(hms(T1)>= hms("00:00:00") & hms(T1)<hms("04:08:00"), "Flood",
                     ifelse(hms(T1)>= hms("04:08:00") & hms(T1)<hms("11:30:00"), "Ebb",
                     ifelse(hms(T1)>= hms("11:30:00") & hms(T1)<hms("18:52:00"), "Flood",
                     ifelse(hms(T1)>= hms("18:52:00") & hms(T1)<hms("23:59:00"), "Ebb", "NA"))))))
```

I first thought it was an interaction around the change of date and time so I split ifelse() statements at midnight to not have the ifelse() span 2 dates (first 2 lines of code). Then I re-ran the code to recreate the dataframe. However that didn't seem to work.

Next, I realized that in the original data for midnight hour there was only one zero in the hours place. I added a second zero to the hours place but it still produced the same result:

```
## Add leading zero, still get same result
test_df2 = data.frame(test_date=c("8/1/2023","8/1/2023","8/1/2023", "7/31/2023","7/31/2023","8/1/2023"),
                     T1=c("16:18:00","17:41:00","18:58:00","23:09:00","23:47:00","00:29:00"),
                     T2=c("17:34:00","18:52:00","19:56:00","23:44:00","00:28:00","01:21:00"),
                     mid_time=c("16:56:00","18:16:30","19:27:00","23:26:30","00:07:30","00:55:00"))

test_df2 = test_df2 %>%
  mutate(DateTime1=as.POSIXct(with(test_df2, as.Date(test_date,"%m/%d/%y%y")+hms(T1)))) %>%
  mutate(DateTime2=as.POSIXct(with(test_df2, as.Date(test_date,"%m/%d/%y%y")+hms(T2)))) %>%
  mutate(midtime_date=as.POSIXct(with(test_df2, as.Date(test_date,"%m/%d/%y%y")+hms(mid_time)))) 

test_df2 = test_df2 %>%
  
  mutate(Tide=ifelse(midtime_date>="2023-07-31 18:14:00 UTC" & midtime_date<"2023-07-31 23:22:00 UTC","EBB",
                     ifelse(midtime_date>="2023-07-31 23:22:00 UTC" & midtime_date<="2023-07-31 23:59:00 UTC","Flood",
                     ifelse(midtime_date>="2023-08-01 00:00:00 UTC" & midtime_date<"2023-08-01 04:08:00 UTC","Flood",
                     ifelse(midtime_date>="2023-08-01 04:08:00 UTC" & midtime_date<"2023-08-01 11:30:00 UTC","Ebb",
                     ifelse(midtime_date>="2023-08-01 11:30:00 UTC" & midtime_date<"2023-08-01 18:52:00 UTC","Flood",
                     ifelse(midtime_date>="2023-08-01 18:52:00 UTC" & midtime_date<"2023-08-02 00:00:00 UTC","Ebb",
                                                        "NA" )))))))
# What I want
test_df2 = test_df2 %>%
  
  mutate(Tide=ifelse(test_date=="2023-07-31",
                     ifelse(hms(T1)>= hms("18:14:00") & hms(T1)<hms("23:22:00"), "Ebb", "Flood" ), 
                     
                     ifelse(hms(T1)>= hms("00:00:00") & hms(T1)<hms("04:08:00"), "Flood",
                     ifelse(hms(T1)>= hms("04:08:00") & hms(T1)<hms("11:30:00"), "Ebb",
                     ifelse(hms(T1)>= hms("11:30:00") & hms(T1)<hms("18:52:00"), "Flood",
                     ifelse(hms(T1)>= hms("18:52:00") & hms(T1)<hms("23:59:00"), "Ebb", "NA"))))))
```

Now I'm not sure what to try next given that it worked for all values except these 3. As you can see I figured out a viable work around that will be fine but I would really like to understand what is going on with the dates and time in the logical statements and why it worked in some cases and not others.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064) What time zone are you in?

Comment: @MrFlick - I updated the post to provide additional clarity and to add data and code that reproduces the problem and solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite hard to make heads or tails of your code. While I wouln't say it's spaghetti code, your question could do with a description, to tell us what you are trying to do, or, if nothing else, at least a desired output. I'm guessing the last test_df2 is the desired output, but I'm still unsure if that is actually the case.

```
ebb_flood <- function(v) {
  case_when(
    v <= hms("04:08:00") ~ "Flood",
    v <= hms("11:30:00") ~ "Ebb",
    v <= hms("18:52:00") ~ "Flood",
    v <= hms("23:59:00") ~ "Ebb",
    TRUE ~ NA_character_
  )
}

test_df |> mutate(Tide = hms(T1) |> ebb_flood())
```

Comment: I'm definitely not the most elegant coder. I pretty much only have a hammer in my coding toolbox.  Still fairly new to creating functions so this response helped me learn a lot and eliminates a lot of the code I used to accomplish the same thing. I wasn't aware of case_when() and that is a game changer. Since I found an inelegant solution to produce what I wanted my real question, which got lost in all the text soup, was : #logical: these two statements should be equal but aren't
test_df$midtime_date[6]>"2023-08-01 00:00:00 UTC"
"2023-08-01 00:55:00 UTC">"2023-08-01 00:00:00 UTC"